# Cannot connect to imap Gmail / php imap

Tags: php, ssl, gmail, imap

While trying to use php's imap functions I can't connect to Gmail's imap server.
I'm using:

```
$mail = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', '******@gmail.com', '******') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Which returns this message:

Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /blabla/mail-handler.php on line 18
Cannot connect to Gmail: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco
(which seems to cut off).

I've also tried:

```
imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl
```

Also tried to connect via server with/without ssl certificate.
Can someone tell what I'm missing here?

According to phpinfo() imap is available.
Also, the less secure apps setting is on (as is imap) in Gmail's settings

Comment: Yes Gmail are by default refusing IMAP connections, you have to make sure imap is enabled in the settings, that multiple factor authentication is off, but even doing this, you may still get rejected if google thinks the incoming connection is not to be trusted.

Comment: imap is turned on in the Gmail settings

Comment: Did you, umm, log in from your browser on the same IP you're attempting to run PHP from?

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but I had the same problem. It has to do with PHP IMAP security. You will need to allow less secure apps. View details [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

Comment: He said in his question he had enabled 'Less Secure Apps'.

Comment: I have enabled Less Secure Apps but still I am getting "Can't do secure authentication with this server"